# Fast lookup IPv4 Set

Tags: c, data-structures, hash, ip

I've been doing some homework on which data structure is best for optimized lookup of IPv4 addresses to implement in C.  I don't need key-value, just to check if it's present in a set.  I can't have false positives, so no bloom filter.  Most of the options recommended (radix tree, y-fast tree) are for key-value storage.  I've considered a hash table, but don' t need to store a value, just a key.  What's the best way to do this with fast lookups as the foremost concern?

Comment: IP addresses are just 4 byte numbers, so store them in a sorted list and do a binary search.

Comment: Interval trees are nice.

Comment: BTW: you dont *need* to store a value. So: hashmap/bitmask, or hashtab, or interval-tree.

Comment: The fastest way will probably be to allocate half a gigabyte of RAM (2^32 bits) and treat it as a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, with very little work you can change the structure to treat the key as the value itself. Such sorted-set, which might be based on a skip-list, will be leaner.